# For loop in python programming?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I am just learning Python with ebook of A Byte in Python and some youtube tutorial. I have reached up to For loop statement. Its not that I don't understand it, but the beginner examples only show: " for i in range..." My question is why only 'in range' option is given. I know how this statement, both for and range, works. But are there other options instead of range? 
  Can you give me a simple Syntax for usage of for loop? They don't have it in this ebook. Thanks and sorry if I was irritating and confusing. I am just learning by myself.

Comment: `range` is just a built-in function that returns an iterator. You can loop over any iterable object(e.g. `for line in file_object`, `for key in dictionary`, `for element in list`, `for character in string`). You can think of python's `for` as `foreach` in other languages. Note that if you want to have access to both index and elements you can use `enumerate`: `for index, element in enumerate(iterable)`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, there are many ways to use a for-loop. `for i in range()` is commonly used to loop through something a specific amount of times, or just do something a repeated amount of times with a counter.

Infact, you don't even have to iterate over lists. You can iterate over a string:

```
>>> for char in 'hello':
...     print char
... 
h
e
l
l
o
```

Or even a dictionary:

```
>>> for key in {'foo':'bar','cabbage':'cake'}:
...     print key
... 
cabbage
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Python does not have the typical for loop construct that the "c-family" languages like java, c, c++, etc have. Python isn't the only scripting language that does this ( I believe bash does it too but don't quote me ). If you want something as true as can be to the "normal" for loop ( and I'm assuming you do ) :

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ){ /* do something */ }
```

I would suggest a while loop in python

```
i = 0
while ( i < n ) : 
    // do something
```

Or use `xrange`

```
for i in xrange( 0, n ) : 
    // do something
```

xrange is a lot like range, but it doesn't store all the values simultaneously : http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

I personally would use xrange, I don't know of a better solution. Good luck!